# Asp.Net core ActionFilter - how to pass varying number of parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'd like to pass varying number of parameters to an ActionFilter. example:

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(AuthorizeFilter), Arguments = new object[] {PolicyName.CanUpdateModule, PolicyName.CanReadModule })]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutModule([FromRoute] Guid id, [FromBody] Module module)
```

I defined filter like below and I get the error
"InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'MyApp.AuthFilters.AuthorizeFilter' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.". How do I get around this issue?

```
public class AuthorizeFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IAuthorizationService _authService;
    private readonly string[] _policyNames;

    public AuthorizeFilter(IAuthorizationService authService,params string[] policyNames)
    {
        _authService = authService;
        _policyNames = policyNames.Select(f => f.ToString()).ToArray();
    }...
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you specify the arguments in constructor like `public AuthorizeFilter(IAuthorizationService authService, string canUpdate, string canRead)`

Comment: Yes, it does work, if declared individually.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Close but no cigar. You are calling your filter with the wrong parameters. You already are calling it as a `TypeFilterAttribute`, since you need DI *and* arguments passed in.

Now you just need to fix your arguments. You want to pass in a string array, but you pass in several strings.

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(AuthorizeFilter), 
    Arguments = new object[] {
        new string[] { PolicyName.CanUpdateModule,  PolicyName.CanReadModule }
    }
)]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutModule([FromRoute] Guid id, [FromBody] Module module) {
    /*do stuff*/
}
```

Nontheless, your `IAuthorizationService` still needs to be registered with your DI container, to be resolved.

Then you need to remove your `params` keyword from your `AuthorizeFilter` class:

```
public class AuthorizeFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IAuthorizationService _authService;
    private readonly string[] _policyNames;

    public AuthorizeFilter(IAuthorizationService authService,string[] policyNames)
    {
        _authService = authService;
        _policyNames = policyNames;
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This fixed the issue.